# how can I http post a JSON file using an excel on both Windows and Mac

Tags: json, excel, macos, vba, http

I currently have a spreadsheet where a macro creates a JSON string and posts it to a web service using HTTP. On windows this code works fine for this:

```
Private Sub pvPostString(sUrl As String, sString As String, sFileName As String, Optional ByVal bAsync As Boolean)

    Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"
    Dim nFile           As Integer
    Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
    Dim sPostData       As String
    Dim connUrl         As String

    sPostData = sString

    '--- prepare body
    sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        sPostData & vbCrLf & _
        "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"
    '--- post
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY
        .Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
    End With

End Sub
```

However on the latest Mac Excel I get an error "ActiveX component can't create object". This makes sense as MSXML2.XMLHTTP is a Microsoft solution, however it means I need to find a replacement function.

I've done lots of googling on this matter and from what I have read I may be able to achieve this using query tables. However, I have tried all sorts of configurations but with no joy. For example if I try the following then I get the error "Invalid web query"

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connUrl, Destination:=Range("C30"))
        .PostText = myJSONString
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .Refresh
End With
```

This makes sense as JSON isn't valid post text, though at the same time posting a lengthy JSON file as post text doesn't really seem like the right solution.

Ideally I would like to post the JSON as a file so that it can be referenced on the server by $_FILES[]. Though from what I've read it isn't clear on how to do this (or if it is possible at all).

tldr; Ultimately my objective with this is to have a function that allows me to post a lengthy JSON string via http that will work on both Windows and Mac. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

[VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) (previously Excel-REST) supports both Windows in Mac in v4.0.0 and allows you to GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE from VBA. I haven't tried it with file uploads, so I'm not sure it will work in your case, but I'd give it a try. Here's a sample:

```
' Replace with the following
' With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
'     .Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
'     .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY
'     .Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
' End With

' Client for executing requests
Dim Client As New WebClient
' Generally set Client.BaseUrl here, but it's not required

' Request for setting request details
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpPost
Request.Resource = sUrl
Request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY

' Execute request and store response
Dim Response As WebResponse
Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
```